# The number of positive integral solutions of the equation $x_1x_2x_3x_4x_5=1050$?

Tags: combinatorics

> The number of positive integral solutions of the equation
>   $x_1x_2x_3x_4x_5=1050$ ?

I prime factorized 1050.Then what to do?

Comment: No.Please read the question carefully @mrprottolo

Comment: You  can also separate numbers

Comment: $2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot5\cdot7$ and $3\cdot2\cdot5\cdot5\cdot7$ are the same solution or different?

Comment: @GEdgar different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is

$$10\cdot5^3+5^4=15\cdot125=1875$$

Think of the $x_i$'s as a row of $5$ boxes into which you're going to throw the prime numbers $2$, $3$, $5$, $5$, and $7$ (whose product is $1050$).  The two $5$'s either go into *separate* boxes, or they go together.  There are ${5\choose2}=10$ ways they can go into separate boxes and $5$ ways they can go together.  The other primes have $5$ choices each.

Comment: Isn't there 5 boxes not 4?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I misread (or miscounted).  I'll fix it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$1050 = 2\cdot 3 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 7$. Do for each power of a prime separately. Say, for $y_1y_2 y_3 y_4= 2$ there are $4$ solutions, 
while for $y_1y_2 y_3 y_4= 5^2$ there are $4+ 6 = 10$. From each solution for the separate prime powers one gets a solution for the equation. Thus the number is the product of all these numbers $4 \cdot 4 \cdot 10 \cdot 4 = \ldots $

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*

$1$ is also a positive integer !
Arrange the factors in ascending order:

With four $1's : 1$

With three $1's: (2\cdot x_5), (3\cdot x_5),$ etc

With two $1's: (2\cdot3\cdot x_5), (2\cdot5\cdot x_5),$ etc

With one $1:(2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot x_5), (2\cdot3\cdot7\cdot x_5),$ etc

With no $1's: 1$

Work out for each case and add up.

*Further hint:*

There are $4$ distinct factors. If taken one at a time (or four at a time), there will obviously be $4$,
but if taken $2$ at a time,(or $3$ at a time) there will be $\binom42 +\binom31 = 7$
(the second term is when both the $5's$ occur)
The list is $(2,3) (2,5) (2,7) (3,5) (3,7) (5,5) (5,7)$

Now consider the case where three $1's$ are there.
You can either have the remaining two split $1-4$ or $2-3$
Proceed.

---

*Revised formulation after reading clarification to G.Edgar's query*

It now becomes very simple:
The $3$ unique factors can be placed in $5^3$ ways in a row of $5$,
and the $5's$ can be placed in $\binom52$ ways separately, $5$ ways together,
which yields a total of $5^3\cdot15 = 1875$

All places left blank by this process will be filled by a $1$

Comment: Can you make some clarity on it

Comment: What is not clear ?

Comment: Your answer hard to understand what you are tryin to say

Comment: I am adding further hint.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ x_i=2^{a_i}3^{b_i}5^{c_i}7^{d_i}$ for $1\le i\le5$.

Then $a_i=1$ for exactly one $i$, with the remaining $a_i=0;\;$
and similarly for the $b_i$ and $d_i$.

For the $c_i$ we have two cases:

A) $c_i=2$ for exactly one $i$ and the remaining $c_i=0$,

$\;\;\;$in which case there are $5^4=625$ possibilities;

B) $c_i=1$ for exactly two values of $i$ and the remaining $c_i=0$;

$\;\;\;$ in which case there are $5^3\binom{5}{2}=1250$ possibilities.

Therefore there are a total of 1875 solutions of this form.

Answer (score 1):

The $2$ must divide some $x_i$, so there are $5$ options for which $x_i$ it divides. Similarly for the $3$ and the $7$.

The $5$s can be distributed amongst the $x_i$ in $5+\binom{5}{2}=15$ ways, counting where $25$ divides some $x_i$ and where the $5$s are separated as dividing two distinct $x_i$.

So there are $5\cdot5\cdot5\cdot15=1875$ solutions.